# R: excluding all duplicates rows (both of each pair) based on one column

Tags: r, bash

I have a file (called example.txt) that looks like the following:

```
A B C  
D E F  
H I C  
Z B Y  
A B C  
T E F  
W O F
```

Based on column 2, I would like to identify the duplicate rows to obtain the following file:

```
H I C  
W O F
```

Comment: `df[ave(seq_along(df$col2), df$col2, FUN = length) == 1,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just compute which values occur exactly once and select those rows - like this:

```
Tab = table(df$V2)
Vals = unlist(attr(Tab, "dimnames"))[which(Tab == 1)]
df[df$V2 %in% Vals, ]
  V1 V2 V3
3  H  I  C
7  W  O  F
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `duplicated`

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1$col2)|duplicated(df1$col2, fromLast=TRUE)),]
#   col1 col2 col3
#3    H    I    C
#7    W    O    F
```